# Research in Financial Mathematics - Questions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, harmonic-analysis

I would like to ask recommendations on what I should focus my time on. I have just admiration for the vast world of mathematics and I would like to learn as much as I possibly can. However, I would like to prioritize the more relevant topics first. My work revolves around financial mathematics. In particular, I would like to specialize in (1) Stochastic Analysis, (2) Probability Theory, and (3) Optimization.

My current background includes: (1) Real Analysis, (2) Measure Theory, (3) Abstract Algebra, (4) Differential Geometry, (5) Algebraic Geometry, (6) Basics of Probability Theory. I have completed all of Folland so I have elementary knowledge of Functional and Fourier Analysis. My probability knowledge is from completing Williams. I do not want to gain knowledge for employability, instead I would like to one day be able to produce meaningful research in financial mathematics.

Now, I am not sure to what extent I would require other topics for my goal of gaining a deep understanding of financial mathematics. As of right now, I was contemplating going through Rudin's book on Functional Analysis.*(**Question 1.**)* Would a cover-to-cover read prove worthwhile? Meaning, is such knowledge on Functional Analysis needed in my field or would my background from Folland be sufficient? I would most definitely finish it one day but for now I would like to focus on any and everything that has direct application to finance going through the most relevant material first.*(**Question 2.**)* Moreover, what about fields like Harmonic and Microlocal Analysis? Should learning such topics be of priority to someone trying to specialize in financial math?

From what information is available online, I have read that knowledge of Partial Differential Equations is particularly useful.*(**Question 3.**)* Is it useful to go into depth or would a shallow background suffice? If you could mention some textbooks on the level that would prove most efficient for my time, I would be extremely grateful.

As per what I have currently planned, I would simply be devoting my time towards getting through a text on Stochastic Calculus *(Karatzas and Shreve)* and one on Stochastic Differential Equations *(Oksendal)*.

I have three years to kill before I finish my undergraduate program. Till then, I have no responsibility and am as free as a bird. I feel like that much time would suffice to get a thorough understanding of financial mathematics. Finishing my question, I would like to restate that I do not want to gain knowledge for employability, instead I would like to one day be able to produce meaningful research in financial mathematics. I would, again, be **extremely** grateful if someone could answer my questions.

Comment: I have reposted my question—this time asking more explicit questions. I hope this would be fine.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!, Your question looks a bit too long, it would be preferable if you organize your question better next time

Comment: @GAUSS1860 Sorry, I should have summarized it a bit more but I was scared of leaving any information which might influence the answers. I will try to organize it better next time. Even though I have plenty of time, I would still like to add the quote for unknown purposes "If I had more time, I would have written a shorter letter".

Comment: I understand but some users might flag your question. I could offer you my opinion on the field of mathematical optimization I would recommend you to study Numerical Linear Algebra and perhaps Nonlinear Optimization and Monte Carlo methods (thought it might be too advanced).

Comment: Q1: good functional analysis background alway pays off at some point. Q2: not too important Q3: certainly important and will be needed for understanding stochastic analysis anyway. Priority for math finance should be parabolic PDEs. Studying those can be nicely combinded with stoch. analysis and also functional analysis - keyword: semigroups. For math. finance you should also consider digging into numerics and recent developments in machine learning etc. Yet another interesting field might be large deviations. Well, that's enough to fill years already ;)

Comment: @Tobsn I would restate that I very much appreciate you spending your time to guide me through the mist. Q1: Do you have a specific book in mind? I don't know whether I should tackle some of the more advanced books or I should just stop after a solid introduction. I think you might like the book by Brezis, a PDF of the book is the first link if you search 'Brezis Functional Analysis'. It's oriented towards PDEs and Sobolev Spaces Theory and you seem like a PDE guy. Do you think a good run through the book will help me cover the PDE and Functional Analysis side for me?

Comment: @Tobsn Q3: Thank you for recommending these subjects. Statistics and Machine Learning has been something I've been wanting to learn after I get a good basis in pure mathematics There is so much to learn I can't decipher between what will actually prove fruitful and what just seems that way. It's like being a kid at a candy shop with only 10$ in my pocket. I hope you the best.